# Would love some help determining where to start with the Node.JS app file provided with BlueMix

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud

I've been reading tutorials for JS and I've got a good idea of the syntax and methodology, now I'm looking to figure out how to use Node.JS to build an app with BlueMix. I'm pretty fluent with Java, but I'm absolutely new to web programming so I'm pretty lost as to how to start. Forgive my current state of being an absolute beginner, but I'm just really stuck. Here's the file they give you to build off of.

```
/*eslint-env node*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require('express');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {

// print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

To clarify, I get the general purpose of the code - it's commented pretty well, but I just don't know how to start // test on the BlueMix platform. I tried doing things like adding print statements, but nothing really changes.

To give a little insight on what I'm trying to do: Just create a webpage where a user can input a string and I can post a string in response. I'm just trying to learn BlueMix, so I need to do it on this platform, and in Node JS.

Comment: where to start, for what? node-js hello world?

Comment: basically! if i could get a hello world-esque app running bluemix, I'd have no trouble writing an application. I'm kind of just stuck at understanding how to write/run an app with bluemix

Comment: ok, but blue mix is more/less hosting, right? But it seems like you have problems with printing some `hello world`, correct? Or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: maybe `npm install & npm start`

Comment: for instance, let's say I just want to create a blank html page that says "hello world." where would I put it? i'm guessing inside the app.listen() block? when I hit deploy and try to run the app, nothing really shows up

Comment: one of the things I don't understand is why nothing really happens when I start the program - it never prints "starting server"

Comment: echo "hello" >> public/index.html;

Comment: how did you start it?

Comment: I'm not sure what that line did - should I just copy it directly into my program? I'm just hitting the "deploy" button in bluemix, which then runs the program

Comment: OK, I guess it's something bluemix specific.. try to replace `appEnv.port` with 3000 (for example) and run your server like a normal express one..

Comment: Ahh your are developing in the cloud on bluemix server? Then ask the support there..

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to take a look at this tutorial: [IBM Bluemix DevOps Services - Develop and deploy a Node.js app](https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/jazzeditor/). It is useful to get started with DevOps Services (reading your comments it seems that you are using it to deploy from the Web IDE to Bluemix) to get a "Hello World" Node.js Web application on Bluemix. It also shows how to apply some changes and re-push them directly on Bluemix.

Just to answer to your questions, assuming that you have already deployed the starter application (as in your example):

1. Consider that the starter application uses Express.js, that is an application server framework that helps you to manage the incoming requests. Now let's say that you want to send the string "Hello, World!" in HTTP response when the server receives an HTTP GET request (let's say /printhello). Using express you'll have something like:

> app.get('/printhello', function (req, res) {
>     res.send('Hello, World!');
>   });

2. Now you just need to do the HTTP GET /printhello from a web page (for example the index page under the public folder of the starter application). You could for example use an *onclick* event to send the request to the server. You will see that the server receives it and sends the response to the browser, that will show the string "Hello, World!".
3. The reason why you can't see the "starting server" log is that *console.log* prints in the Node.js console, not into the HTTP response, so you can't see that from the client. To see that output you can use *cf logs* (please refer to [this blog post](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/29/accessing-application-logs-bluemix/)).

Finally, I invite you to take a look at the [Bluemix - Node.js SDK](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/nodejs/index.html#nodejs) documentation, it is really simple and clear.

I hope this can give you some starting points.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluemix-hello-node.  It provides a pretty good starting place for node.  There are somethings you need to code around for Node to work for Bluemix.  The biggest is binding to the correct port, the port is given through `process.env.PORT`.  I have pasted a super simple Node.app below (the rest of the code is at the GitHub link above).

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/hello", function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"})
    response.end("Hello World!\n");
});

app.listen(port);
```